# Instance_name in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I want to understand the difference between v$instance and parameter: instance_name. This is with reference to regular Oracle 12c database **not using a RAC environment or setup.**

My pfile excerpt

```
instance_name=test
db_name=r12g1
db_domain=us.<>.com
service_names=test.us.<>.com
```

When I queried as:

```
select INSTANCE_NUMBER, INSTANCE_NAME, HOST_NAME, STATUS from v$instance;

1 r12g1 <machine name> OPEN
```

Whereas:

```
show parameter instance_name;
```

Shows as:

```
instance_name   string   test
```

Why is there a discrepancy? 
Also, if i notice the list of "pmon" process in the OS, it is as: ora_pmon_**r12g1**

Comment: Funny. Connected to the container of a plugin database? Using a dba account?

Comment: No, not trying to create a CDB. Yes, logging as DBA.

Answer (score 0):

The db_name is the name of your database.
A database is a set of files (data files, redologs, control files..)

The instance name is the name of you instance.
An  instance is a set of backgrounds processes (SMON, PMON, DBWR, etc) and a shared memory segment  (SGA).

A database may be  mounted and opened by many INSTANCES.

In your case you have one instance for one database.
You can stop db and restart it with a new instance_name (=db_name for example)

Comment: Yes. Surely, I can change the instance name (=db_name) (after closing the db). But thats what I want to understand. If the DB supports only one instance (not using RAC), why is there a discrepancy between instance name as mentioned ?

Comment: There is a discrepancy because of your configuration(pfile). When the instance start, it read configuration in pfile(spfile I assume). Change your configuration file and all will be ok.

Comment: So, what difference does the instance name bring in? The background processes are still aligned to SID not instance.

Comment: The ORACLE_SID could be different from db_name!  The oracle sid is used to find  parameter file(pfile or spfile) and to mount a sga. It's why your bg process are  aligned to SID (and not to db_name)